# Prove the equivalence

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone help me through this problem? 
Prove that “equivalence” of smooth curves has the familiar reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties of an equivalence relation
HINT:Use the facts that a 1-1 $C^1$ mapping $λ(t) : [c, d] →[a, b]$ with $λ>0$ has a 1-1
$C^{1}$ inverse $λ^{−1} : [a, b]→[c, d]$ with $(λ^{−1})>0$ and, if $λ:[c, d]→[a, b]$
and λ2 : [e, f ] → [c, d], then $λ1 ◦ λ2 : [e, f ] → [a, b]$ with all the desired
properties of λ1 and λ2.

The two curves
C1 : z(t), a ≤ t ≤ b
and
C2 : ω(t), c ≤ t ≤ d
are smoothly equivalent if there exists a 1-1 C1 mapping λ(t) : [c, d]→[a, b] such
that λ(c) = a, λ(d) = b, λ(t) > 0 for all t, and
ω(t) = z(λ(t)).

Comment: You should say what your definition of "equivalence" of two smooth curves is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean "re-paramatrization" of $C^1$-curves. Namely, if $\alpha:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta:J\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are two $C^1$ curves we call $\alpha$ a *re-parametrization* of $\beta$ if there there exists a homeomorphism $f:I\to J$ such that $\beta\circ f=\alpha$.

Clearly this is reflexive since we can take $f:I\to I$ to be $\text{id}$.

It's transitive for the composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism.

Now, you work to prove it's symmetric. If $f:I\to J$ is a homeomorphism such that $\beta\circ f=\alpha$ we want a homeomorphism $g:J\to I$ such that $\beta=\alpha\circ g$. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it valid to the definition given below of this exercise?

Comment: No, it's not. I used homeomorphism instead of $C^1$ map. That said, my same advice goes with the swapping of those two words and the fact that the inverse of a positive injective $C^1$ map is necessarily $C^1$ (as they indicated).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rigorous proof, for the sake of completeness.
[I make the same assumption about the set of (smooth) functions you are working on as @Alex Youcis, which I will denote by $S$]

$[$**Reflective property**$]$: Let $c\in S,$ τότε $c=c\circ id,$ where $id:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ με $id(t)=t,$ i.e. $c\sim c.$

$[$**Symmetry**$]$: Let $a,b\in S$ with $a\sim b,$ (i.e. $b$ is a re-parametrization of $a$), then there exist a smooth ($C^{1}$) homeomorphism $\phi$ such that $a=b\circ\phi$. Then, $b=a\circ\phi^{-1}$, i.e. $b\sim a.$

$[$**Transitive**$]$: Let $a,b,c\in S$ with $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c,$ (i.e. $b$ is a re-parametrization of  $a$ and $c$ is a re-parametrization of $b$). Then there exist smooth ($C^{1}$) homeomorphisms $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ such that $b=a\circ\phi_{1}$ and $c=b\circ\phi_{2}$.  Then, $\psi:=\phi_{1}\circ\phi_{2}$ is also a smooth ($C^{1}$) homeomorphism and  $$c=b\circ\phi_{1}=(a\circ\phi_{1})\circ\phi_{2}=a\circ(\phi_{1}\circ\phi_{2})=a\circ\psi$$ i.e. $a\sim c.$